# How to intercept all the network requests of resources for a Web Page?

Tags: android, html, http, chromium

A webpage loading includes resources like JavaScript, CSS and many other kinds of files. I want to intercept all those network request of resources in Chromium code. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: post some code of what you have tried

Comment: press `F12` and select the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho)

**Stetho** is a sophisticated debug bridge for Android applications. When enabled, developers have access to the Chrome Developer Tools feature natively part of the Chrome desktop browser.

Once you complete the set-up instructions, just start your app and point your browser to `chrome://inspect` . Click the "Inspect" button to begin.

**Set-up**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'
```

you may also wish to use one of the network helpers:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1'
```

or:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-urlconnection:1.5.1'
```

depends upon your case

also put below code in your Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
  }
}
```

Also ensure that your `MyApplication` class is registered in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        ...>
        <application
                android:name="MyApplication"
                ...>
         </application>
</manifest>
```