# Where I can find web logs or something like that in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I have been developing app for android at Android Studio. At my project I'm using `Retrofit` and some others libraries. At one part of my app I have `WebView` which can load received url and show page content. I saw that smb at SO asked some questions which was connected with such web logcat. For example at ordinary logcat I can see all requests which are done by `Retrofit` library. It means I can check everything from headers to received data. But can I see sent and received data at webview? At Chrome for example I can see smth like logs at developer mode. I will need to add headers to my url which then will be loaded at webview and I will need to see it and also I'm interested in seeing data which I will receive.

### UPDATE

I have found at profiler this [tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler) but I can't select range for observing income data, maybe I have to reinstall AS? Here is example of networking profiler:
[image]

so how I can select range?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55373851/4649110

Comment: You can extend WebViewClient, override "onPageStarted" method and add logging there. Then just add it to webView with WebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client)

Comment: @anro, how I can add logging? I have onPageStarted but I don't know how to add logging

Comment: @Basi, as I see I have to add only one line at gradle and one line at webiew activity?

Comment: Something like Log.i(TAG, url);

Comment: @anro, I don't need getting url, I need to see sent and received data like at retrofit logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it looks like I managed to find web logs at AS. It is placed at profiler tool. Here you have to enter to network and then you will see all requests-responses. For diving at received-sent data you have to enable this:
[image]

then you will have to enter to profiler and select period:

[image]

I hope it will help someone else except me :)